# Whirring that stops when you accelerate

Tags: ford, noise, explorer

My vehicle just started making a loud whirring sound from somewhere underneath.  It only happens at highway speeds (50+ mph).

Strangely, the whirring *stops* as soon as I step on the gas, though it comes back again quickly.

What's likely to be causing this?

The vehicle is a 1996 Ford Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a sound swelling in volume as you reach a certain speed, like between 50-60mph, my guess would be the propshaft. If the uni-joints (or cv's) are shot, it's common to experience such a sound in such a manner. I'd check for play on them. They're probably easily accessible and inspectable by only jacking up the side of the car.

Comment: When the sound happens, it starts suddenly without any buildup or swell.

Comment: It may still be those joints then. The natural frequency of e.g. the car's body amplifies sounds like whirring when they're at a specific frequency. That's why sounds may become audible only it at certain speeds/revs. If it's only at certain speeds, i'd suspect the propshaft.